# Python - how to convert stringed arrays within arrays to float arrays

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

python noob here. i tried to read in from a text file that contain fields of arrays and append to a list but i keep getting error that the array inside the array are string instead of float.

from the text file;

```
[81.48, 74.02, 4.03, 23.18, 211359232.0];[0.007, -0.006, -0.082, 0.075, -0.153];[-0.014, 0.025, 0.06, 0.085, 0.014]
```

i read in the text, split it, converted to np.array and append to an array cumulatively but it doesnt seem to work.
the array inside the array is a string 
e.g.

```
['[82.04, 73.6, 3.7, 24.93, 179081216.0]', '[83.3, 74.0, 3.41, 24.97, 175265792.0]', '[82.94, 74.75, 3.41, 27.62, 177734656.0]'
```

i am trying to convert it to without the '

```
[[82.04, 73.6, 3.7, 24.93, 179081216.0], [83.3, 74.0, 3.41, 24.97,175265792.0], [82.94, 74.75, 3.41, 27.62, 177734656.0]]


import numpy as np
f=open('/home/oracle/adpo/result_run_output.txt','r')
x=[]

for line in f:
   line=line.rstrip('\n')
   a = line.split(';')
   b = np.array(a[2])
   x.append(b
```

ultimately is to be used to generate out a correlation matrix. please advise and thanks.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what exactly is in your file?

Comment: this is my text input file.
94;93,1100,41,10,44,100,700,all_rows,force;[81.64, 75.53, 3.67, 24.62, 223766016.0];[0.005, -0.026, 0.008, 0.013, -0.2];[0.003, 0.002, 0.011, 0.072, -0.028]
95;94,1500,81,0,16,700,1300,all_rows,force;[81.81, 74.41, 3.7, 24.19, 216762368.0];[0.003, -0.011, 0.0, 0.031, -0.174];[-0.002, 0.015, -0.008, 0.018, 0.032]

Comment: How did this file come to be? Why are you using some ad-hoc serialization format? Why not the supported `npy` format for `numpy.ndarray` objects, or `pickle`,  or even JSON?

Comment: @CKHuang, you need to edit that into the question.  If you indent it like you did your code, that will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: i was converting the output from another program to string before writing out to file using file.write(str(field1)+str(field2)+str(field3))

Comment: You must split the string twice: first by ";" (row split), then by "," (column split).

Comment: thanks DyZ for reformatting my question. this is my first post here and i have tried numerous method before i hit the wall. so what should i do after splitting the columns in the extracted stringed array?

Comment: @CKHuang but why would you do this? Why wouldn't you use a well-supported serialization format, rather than cooking up your own?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, i just picked up python not long ago. still learning the ropes and starting from basic. any recommendation?

Comment: Yes. use `numpy.save` or `pickle` or JSON

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks alot.. i will look them up

Answer (score 0):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga correctly observed, you should not have been inventing your formats. But since you did, and, luckily, your rows look like JSON arrays, the following code may help:

```
import json
data = """[81.48, 74.02, 4.03, 23.18, 211359232.0];[...]"""

array = np.array([json.loads(row) for row in data.split(';')])
```